# Cannot compile code with maven with github actions

Tags: java, github-actions

I just set up my github actions using yml files and the first one sets up correctly but refuses to compile and I get Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/Project/Project/article'. No such file or directory

This is the yml file:

```
name: Article module development-CI

on:
  workflow_call:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "dev"
    paths:
      - 'article/**'
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/setup-jdk.yml
    with:
      working-directory: 'article'

  compile:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Compile code with maven ️
        working-directory: 'article'
        run: mvn compile

  test:
    needs: compile
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run tests with maven 
        working-directory: 'article'
        run: mvn test
```

The checkout is done here :

```
name: Setup JDK and Checkout Code

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      java-version:
        description: 'Java version'
        required: false
        default: '18'
        type: string
      working-directory:
        description: 'Working directory'
        required: false
        default: '.'
        type: string

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout branch ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}

      - name: Set up JDK ${{ inputs.java-version }} ️
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: ${{ inputs.java-version }}
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven
```

Comment: Don't you need to checkout your code? Something like: `uses: actions/checkout@v4`?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple jobs and each job runs in a new virtual environment. Your previous JDK setup and repo checkout have to be done again. If you would have one job with more steps it would be sufficient. Check here for reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#the-components-of-github-actions

Comment: It could almost be an indentation problem. But your answer covers it well.